# Magento 2 Why isn't this UpgradeData.php code work

Tags: php, attributes, magento2, categories

I want to add some new category attributes along with a new category attribute group to group them all under.

The upgrade is being ran with no errors but it doesn't seem to run the code even though it looks perfect to me. Am I missing something?

**UpgradeData.php**

```
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4', '<')) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $eavSetup->addAttributeGroup(
                Category::ENTITY,
                $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Category::ENTITY),
                'Thirdlight Settings',
                99
            );

            $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'thirdlight_banner', [
                'type'     => 'string',
                'label'    => 'Thirdlight Banner',
                'input'    => 'text',
                'source'   => '',
                'visible'  => true,
                'default'  => '',
                'required' => false,
                'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'    => 'Thirdlight Settings',
            ]);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

**Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Avery_Orderattribs" setup_version="1.0.4">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your module `data_version` column is update to 1.0.4 in your `setup_module` database table?

Comment: It should be at 1.0.3 before running the script no?This code checks to see if the current version is lower than 1.0.4 and upgrade the module version after it runs, or am I wrong?

`version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4', '<')`

After I run this it is indeed at 1.0.4 though

Comment: I make sure Magento can detect a version discrepancy but it still doesn't do anything. My table's timestamp indicates that it has been updated but the data is still not visible. No other post on the subject seem to solve this.